# An error has occurred during report processing. Cannot create datareader for dataset

Tags: c#, pdf, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer, rdlc

I have spent about two days on this and am on my wits end.  Here is the the scenario, I have a rdlc report that renders perfectly fine in a new window if selected.  What I am trying to accomplish is to get the rdlc to export and download a PDF version automatically if that option is selected.  Below is the code for the page and what I am trying to do. I have tried multiple ways to export the PDF but I constantly get the same error as stated in the title. The error happens on the line byte[] bytes = etc etc.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                string orgName = Request.QueryString["orgName"];
                long orgID = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["orgID"]);
                long yearID = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["yearID"]);
                long verID = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["verID"]);
                long prevYearID = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["prevYearID"]);
                long prevVerID = Convert.ToInt64(Request.QueryString["prevVerID"]);
                string oh = Request.QueryString["oh"];
                string pack = Request.QueryString["pack"];


                string iyearID = yearID.ToString();


                ReportParameter pyID = new ReportParameter("pyearID", iyearID);
                this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { pyID });
                ReportParameter poName = new ReportParameter("porgName", orgName);
                this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { poName });
                if (verID == 1)
                {
                    ReportParameter bver = new ReportParameter("pbudVer", "Bid");
                    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { bver });
                }
                else if (verID == 2)
                {
                    ReportParameter bver = new ReportParameter("pbudVer", "First Draft");
                    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { bver });
                }
                else if (verID == 3)
                {
                    ReportParameter bver = new ReportParameter("pbudVer", "Final Draft");
                    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { bver });
                }
                else if (verID == 4)
                {
                    ReportParameter bver = new ReportParameter("pbudVer", "1st Reforecast");
                    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { bver });
                }
                else if (verID == 5)
                {
                    ReportParameter bver = new ReportParameter("pbudVer", "2nd Reforecast");
                    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { bver });
                }
                else if (verID == 6)
                {
                    ReportParameter bver = new ReportParameter("pbudVer", "3rd Reforecast");
                    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { bver });
                }
                else if (verID == 7)
                {
                    ReportParameter bver = new ReportParameter("pbudVer", "4th Reforecast");
                    this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { bver });
                }

                if (pack == "Y")
                {
                    //trythis1();
                    createPdfReport();

                    //SavePDF(Org_Summary);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {

        }


    }

    public void createPdfReport()
    {
        Warning[] warnings;
        string[] streamids;
        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string filenameExtension;


        byte[] bytes = this.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render(
            "PDF", null, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension,
            out streamids, out warnings);

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("output.pdf", FileMode.Create))
        {
            fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried just using LocalReport.Render("PDF") and leaving out all the other parameters. This is how I generate them. Also if you are just going to pdf you can skip using the report viewer and just create an instance of the local report in memory.

Comment: Could you please have a look at my answer on [An error occurred during report processing. RLDC reporting in ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28966954/an-error-occurred-during-report-processing-rldc-reporting-in-asp-net-mvc)?

Comment: This project was abandoned and I was never able to figure it out.  I took a completely different approach on this in the end